# tableHeaderView UISearchBar not showing

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have added a UISearchBar programatically to my UITableView, it was showing perfectly fine untill I decided to add an offset to my UITableView to hide the UISearchBar when the view is loaded. I would like help displaying it again.

This is what my code looks like.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0.0f, 44.0f);

    mySearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 320.0f, 44.0f)];
    mySearchBar.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    mySearchBar.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    mySearchBar.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet;
    mySearchBar.delegate = self;
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = mySearchBar;

    // Create the search display controller
    UISearchDisplayController  *searchController = [[UISearchDisplayController alloc] initWithSearchBar:mySearchBar contentsController:self];
    searchController.searchResultsDataSource = self;
    searchController.searchResultsDelegate = self;
```

I am not really sure where to go to from here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will work in both iOS6 and iOS7.
Note that in iOS7 you will loose transparency of NavigationBar

```
if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {
    self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
}
[self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, mySearchBar.frame.size.height)];
```

If you want to save default transparency in iOS7 use this code:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)]) {

        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, -20)];
    }
    else {
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, mySearchBar.frame.size.height)];
    }
}
```

Comment: yep, it shows perfectly when that line of code is commented out... however I would like to start the view with the 44px offset so the UISearchBar is only accessed when you pull to search./

Comment: @HurkNburkS See full solution.